# How to I deal with '[' and ']' json characters in snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using snowflake.  This is my statement:

```
select
    PARSE_JSON(src): "eventType"::STRING AS eventtype,
    PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(src): "data"::STRING): "events" AS events,
    PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(src): "data"::STRING): "events"): "actor" AS actor,
    PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(src): "data"::STRING): "events"): "actor"): "actor" AS actor2,
    PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON(src): "data"::STRING): "events"): "client" AS client,
    * 
from stage.okta_events
```

This is the data that is in src (one of many. of course):

```
{
  "eventType": "com.okta.event_hook",
  "eventTypeVersion": "1.0",
  "cloudEventsVersion": "0.1",
  "source": "https://liveopsnation.okta.com/api/v1/eventHooks/whom9y9tu9HQdONDc2p7",
  "eventId": "b47d9e73-324e-4f8f-8f28-f6eb17c2fba6",
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "uuid": "ee0a60c9-ee38-11ed-95c3-03faaeb30680",
        "published": "2023-05-09T07:12:59.759Z",
        "eventType": "user.authentication.auth_via_mfa",
        "version": "0",
        "displayMessage": "Authentication of user via MFA",
        "severity": "INFO",
        "client": {
          "userAgent": {
            "rawUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "os": "Windows 10",
            "browser": "CHROME"
          },
          "zone": "null",
          "device": "Computer",
          "ipAddress": "75.181.198.11",
          "geographicalContext": {
            "city": "Charlotte",
            "state": "North Carolina",
            "country": "United States",
            "postalCode": "28202",
            "geolocation": {
              "lat": 35.2316,
              "lon": -80.8428
            }
          },
          "ipChain": [
            {
              "ip": "75.181.198.11",
              "geographicalContext": {
                "city": "Charlotte",
                "state": "North Carolina",
                "country": "United States",
                "postalCode": "28202",
                "geolocation": {
                  "lat": 35.2316,
                  "lon": -80.8428
                }
              },
              "version": "V4"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actor": {
          "id": "00uirbgg60V6N7f2T2p7",
          "type": "User",
          "alternateId": "giovannia1703@outlook.com",
          "displayName": "GIOVANNI ANIEKAN"
        },
        "outcome": {
          "result": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "target": [
          {
            "id": "00uirbgg60V6N7f2T2p7",
            "type": "User",
            "alternateId": "giovannia1703@outlook.com",
            "displayName": "GIOVANNI ANIEKAN"
          }
        ],
        "transaction": {
          "type": "WEB",
          "id": "ZFnyez8n1SOXrJWBHFln0AAABlI",
          "detail": {}
        },
        "debugContext": {
          "debugData": {
            "deviceFingerprint": "62f6b5f088533b8f0c043d332faf6e53",
            "behaviors": "{New Geo-Location=NEGATIVE, New Device=NEGATIVE, New IP=NEGATIVE, New State=NEGATIVE, New Country=NEGATIVE, Velocity=NEGATIVE, New City=NEGATIVE}",
            "promptingPolicyTypes": "[OKTA_SIGN_ON]",
            "requestUri": "/api/v1/authn/factors/dsfj6rbwkd9c37tPm2p7/verify",
            "targetEventHookIds": "whom9y9tu9HQdONDc2p7",
            "url": "/api/v1/authn/factors/dsfj6rbwkd9c37tPm2p7/verify?",
            "authnRequestId": "ZFnydnCxDN2eai4HnmnenQAAA_k",
            "requestId": "ZFnyez8n1SOXrJWBHFln0AAABlI",
            "dtHash": "33327866d72a3400752bef8b0acaec05c4d6f1425408f5cfc546c39902f710db",
            "risk": "{level=LOW}",
            "threatSuspected": "false",
            "factor": "DUO_SECURITY"
          }
        },
        "legacyEventType": "core.user.factor.attempt_success",
        "authenticationContext": {
          "authenticationProvider": "FACTOR_PROVIDER",
          "authenticationStep": 0,
          "externalSessionId": "102LoR0A7c4QLKGDxZjMwEe-A"
        },
        "securityContext": {
          "asNumber": 11426,
          "asOrg": "charter communications inc",
          "isp": "charter communications inc",
          "domain": "spectrum.com",
          "isProxy": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "eventTime": "2023-05-09T07:13:07.213Z",
  "contentType": "application/json"
}
```

What I get is actual data for eventtype and events, but nulls for actor, actor2, and client.

I'm sure that the problem is with the '[' and ']' characters in the json.  How do I deal with those?

Answer (score 0):

Those brackets represent Arrays in JSON. even if they only have one entry per array, you need to use a parsing syntax that handles arrays. You have a couple options.

This would be the simplest, and will work as long as you know that the events array will only ever have one record

```sql
select 
    PARSE_JSON(src) as JSON,
    JSON:eventType::STRING AS eventtype,
    JSON:data:events AS events,
    JSON:data:events[0]:actor AS actor,
    JSON:data:events[0]:actor:displayName::STRING AS actor_name,
    JSON:data:events[0]:client AS client
from stage.okta_events
```

If a record has multiple event records in one json blob (meaning you can't just grab the "first" one), then you can use this syntax to split each into its own row in the output.

```sql
select 
    PARSE_JSON(src) as JSON,
    JSON:eventType::STRING AS eventtype,
    e.value AS events,
    e.value:actor AS actor,
    e.value:actor:displayName::STRING AS actor_name,
    e.value:client AS client
from stage.okta_events,
lateral flatten(input => JSON:data:events) e;
```

I also took the liberty of cleaning up unnecessary casting and re-parsing from your example.

Comment: I also wrote a blog on this topic if you are interested in more tips for parsing JSON in Snowflake: https://medium.com/snowflake/querying-json-in-snowflake-a-color-coded-e-578d01445284